# html;css margin:0 auto; выравнивание по центру

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Локально подключен bootstrap,возможно запутался в наследовании..

```css
.main-section.team{
  padding:85px 0;
 }
.main-section.team h6{
 margin-bottom:40px;
}



.team-leader-block{
 max-width:993px;
 margin:0 auto;
}
.team-leader-box{
 width:30.66%;
 margin-right: 3.82979%;
 height: 490px;
 overflow: hidden;
 text-align: center;
 float: left;
}
.team-leader-box span{
 margin-bottom:24px;
 display:block;
}
.team-leader-box:nth-of-type(3n+0){ margin:0;}
.team-leader{
 width:auto;
 height:auto;
 position:relative;
 border-radius:50%;
 box-shadow:0px 0px 0px 7px rgba(241,241,241,0.80);
 margin:7px 7px 25px 7px;

}
.team-leader-shadow{
 transition:all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition:all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 -webkit-transition:all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 border-radius:50%;
 position:absolute;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 z-index:10;
 border-radius:50%;
}
.team-leader-shadow a{
 display:block;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
}
.team-leader:hover .team-leader-shadow{
 box-shadow:inset  0px 0px 0px 148px rgba(17,17,17,0.80);
}
.team-leader:hover ul{ display:block; opacity:1}
.team-leader img{
 display:block;
 border-radius:50%;
}
.team-leader ul{
 display:block;
 opacity:0;
 padding:0;
 margin:0;
 list-style:none;
 position:absolute;
 left:0;
 top:50%;
 width:100%;
 text-align:center;
 margin-top:-14px;
 z-index:15;
 transition:all 0.6s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition:all 0.6s ease-in-out;
 -webkit-transition:all 0.6s ease-in-out;
}
.team-leader ul li{
 display:inline;
 margin:0 11px;
}
.team-leader ul li a{
 font-family: 'FontAwesome';
 display:inline-block;
 font-size:28px;
 color:#fff;
 transition:all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition:all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 -webkit-transition:all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.team-leader ul li a:hover, .team-leader ul li a:focus{
 text-decoration:none;
}
```

```html
<section class="main-section cv" id="cv" style="margin:0 auto;">
  <!--t section start-->
  <div class="container">
   <h2>text</h2>
   <h6>Take a closer look</h6>
   <div class="team-leader-block clearfix" style="margin:0 auto; !important">
    <div class="team-leader-box">
     <div class="team-leader wow fadeInDown delay-06s">
      <div class="team-leader-shadow">
       <a href="http://jabascii.zzz.com.ua/cv/"></a>
      </div><img alt="" src="img/prof.jpg">
      <ul>
       <li class="url">
        <a class="fa-letter" href="#"></a>
       </li>
      </ul>
     </div>
     <h3 class="wow fadeInDown delay-06s">Text</h3>
     <p class="wow fadeInDown delay-06s">Text</p>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </section><!--T section end-->
```

[image: Пример кода.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Уберите width у

```
.team-leader-box
```

Задайте нужную ширину

```
.team-leader-block
```

Comment: Спасибо,все исправил,и ничего не плывет теперь:)

Answer (score 0):

html в верхнем посте скинул кривой.

```html
<section class="main-section team" id="team">
  <!--t section start-->
  <div class="container">
   <h2>text</h2>
   <h6>Take a closer look</h6>
   <div class="team-leader-block clearfix">
    <div class="team-leader-box">
     <div class="team-leader wow fadeInDown delay-06s">
      <div class="team-leader-shadow">
       <a href="url"></a>
      </div><img alt="" src="img/prof.jpg">
      <ul>
       <li class="url">
        <a class="fa-letter" href="#"></a>
       </li>
      </ul>
     </div>
     <h3 class="wow fadeInDown delay-06s">Text</h3>
     <p class="wow fadeInDown delay-06s">Text</p>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </section><!--T section end-->
```